# Diffrence between real and double

Tags: c++, double

```
double real2double(real* r) //This function job is to transform real objects to double
{
    double n = r->num;
    double frac = r->frac; //Saving the number
    while (frac > 1) //Saving the fraction
        frac =frac/10;
    n =n+frac;
    return n;
}
```

I found this function to convert real to double in C++
I'm quite new to this and wonder what is the diffrence between real and double..
why should I even bother converting from one to another

Comment: there are no real numbers. At least not in C++ or in any other programming language. Real numbers have infinite many decimal places by definition

Comment: `double` is a data type in C and C++. `real` is not. It's apparently a type defined somewhere else in the code; it has two data members, one named `num` and one named `frac`. The comments in the code here are rather muddled, so it's hard to say what it actually does. Find its definition.

Comment: perhaps its a misnomer and it should actually be called `rational`. Rational numbers are those that have an integer numerator and denominator.

Comment: @fabian -- it can't be a synonym for `double` because it has data members (named `num` and `frac`).

Comment: `real` must be defined somewhere in code you didn't show, its not a C++ built in type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `real` appears to be a class type. From the usage in the function we can conclude that it has members `frac` and `num` of some type that either is `double` or can be converted to `double`. The members are accessible in the function which implies they are either public or the function is a friend of the class. Making not more assumptions than that, we would expect some definition along the line of:

```
struct real {
    double frac;
    double num;
};
```

> what is the diffrence between real and double..

`real` is a user defined type. `double` is one of C++s [fundamental types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).

Comment: All we can say about the members of `real` named `frac` and `num` are that they are accessible to the function `real2double()`.    That may mean they are `public`.   It may also mean that `real2double()` has been declared as a `friend` of `real`.